# .NET 8 Blazor ssr meta tag content shows hashed for utf-8 characters in browser "View page source"

Tags: c#, blazor, meta-tags, arabic, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor component and set a persian or arabic characters for `HeadContent` meta content:

```
<HeadContent>
    <meta content="@encodedContent" />
    <meta content="@meta" />
</HeadContent>

@code {
    string meta = string.Empty;
    string encodedContent;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        meta = "متن متا فارسی از متد اینیشیال";
        string metaContent = "متن متا فارسی از متد اینیشیال";
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(metaContent);
        string encodedContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

When I write click on browser and select "view page source", it shows:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <base href="/">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OilPriceIran.styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <title>Panel</title><meta />
    <meta content="&#x645;&#x62A;&#x646; &#x645;&#x62A;&#x627; &#x641;&#x627;&#x631;&#x633;&#x6CC; &#x627;&#x632; &#x645;&#x62A;&#x62F; &#x627;&#x6CC;&#x646;&#x6CC;&#x634;&#x6CC;&#x627;&#x644;" /></head>
```

I used `ar` lang and utf-8 meta in `app.razor`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OilPriceIran.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I also added these options to `program.cs` :

```
builder.Services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(
        UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin,
        UnicodeRanges.Arabic);
});
```

But still in "view page source", I see these characters:

```
"&#x645;&#x62A;&#x646; &#x645;&#x62A;"
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Those aren't UTF8 characters. They're HTML entities and will be displayed properly by any browser. There's no need for any kind of encoding to begin with, as this very question proves. StackOverflow is an ASP.NET Core application and this page is UTF8. The calls to `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)` do nothing but return the original string. `encodedContent` isn't encoded at all, it's identical to `metaContent`

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an AppTitle.razor, with the following code:

```
<HeadContent>
    @(new MarkupString($"<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"{Keywords}\" />"))
    @(new MarkupString($"<meta name=\"description\" content=\"{Description}\" />"))
    <title>@(new MarkupString($"{Title} - {AppTitle}"))</title>
</HeadContent>

@code {
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string AppTitle { get; set; } = "XXX";
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const string DefaultKeyWords = "XXX,XXX,XXX,";
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "XXX";
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string Keywords { get; set; } = DefaultKeyWords;
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string Description { get; set; } = DefaultKeyWords;
}
```

Then you can use it this way：

```
<APPTitle Title="XXX" AppTitle="XXX" Keywords="XXX" Description="XXX"></APPTitle>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I have already re edited it

Comment: You may have edited it, but you neglected to add the additional explanation I requested. Can you do that?

Comment: I don't know what explanation you're saying, I think the code is already very clear